# Show Marker View under X axis, at the same height whatever the value is? Using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Currently using MPAndroidChart, I'm willing to know if there is a way to display the markerview under the x axis, and always at the same height.

As and exemple, in the following graph:

[image]

I wish to display the markerview behing the x Axis, just under the corresponding value bar. I succeed to make my own custom marker view but its display position seems to be linked to the top of the corresponding bar, so i"m a little bit stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to display such marker in my graph, can you please share your code snipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an easy solution for this problem.

In this case, you need to `Override` the `draw` method of your custom `MarkerView`.

Here, I can control my x position while **ensuring that the marker remain always on the top of the graph (If you dont want it, use `posy += getYOffset();` instead)**

So this allow me to keep my `MarkerView` above my graph (finally, it's better than below :D ), while avoiding it to have a part of it disapearing on the edge of the screen by controlling the `posx` variable.

A simple example:

```
@Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posx, float posy)
        {
            // take offsets into consideration
            posx += getXOffset();
            posy=0;

            // AVOID RIGHT/LEFT OFFSCREEN
            if(posx<45)
                posx=45;
            if(posx>265)
                posx=265;

            // translate to the correct position and draw
            canvas.translate(posx, posy);
            draw(canvas);
            canvas.translate(-posx, -posy);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by `Override` the `draw` method of custom `MarkerView`.

Just doing `dy = 0` in `canvas.translate(float dx, float dy)`

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posX, float posY) {
    MPPointF offset = getOffsetForDrawingAtPoint(posX, posY);

    int saveId = canvas.save();
    // translate to the correct position and draw
    canvas.translate(posX + offset.x, 0);
    draw(canvas);
    canvas.restoreToCount(saveId);
}
```